# Get jsonp data by webapi

Tags: c#

I use HttpRequest object  to get data from a webapi which repose Jsonp data.But the responseFromServer object  is empty although Chrome Network shows it indeed repose data back.Here is My Code(c#).Greatly appreciated.

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "post";

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    var status = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;

    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: why don't you set a break point in your webapi action, see if your request hit it.And suggest you use `HttpClient` do request.

Comment: Thanks for answering.But it is the  external webapi  so I can't debug.

Comment: if it's working in chrome, then you need check your request code.i'm use `HttpClient` so you need check this `WebRequest` yourself, maybe it's your postData not right, maybe you need decode your recieve stream, debug it.